# An alternative to the Feedback side tab/peeking tab

Tags: buttons

I am trying to build a feedback widget similar to UserVoice or Get Satisfaction for my site. However, I do not want to use that same side tab button opener that they use. I am trying to think of something better and more creative. Could you help me?

Comment: You say "better" - what part of that design doesn't work for your situation, and why?

Comment: @dhmholley It isn't that it doesn't work. I just want something new and improved. Just because it works now, doesn't mean I can't and shouldn't come up with something new.

Answer (score 1):

"Better" doesn't necessarily mean creative.

Why not have a simple feedback tab somewhere at the bottom of the page? People are already used to that idea thanks to Gmail / Facebook...

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/320S2x3F3A1B0O46193W/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-21%20at%2011.33.21%20AM.png)?

Comment: Yeah, something like that.